# Why *.pyc files are being deleted when the associated *.py file is deleted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file, python, process

See update at the end.

I am using Ubuntu Linux 11.10, Python 3.

I wrote a Python script which converts some Qt *.ui files to *.py using pyuic4. Then i want to compile the obtained *.py file to *.pyc and delete the *.py file.

For some reason when i delete a converted *.py file, the *.pyc version is also deleted:

```
try:
    command = 'pyuic4 -o /home/vic/ui_form.py /home/vic/form.ui'
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell= True, stderr= subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('Failed:', e.output)
else:
    print('Converted %s to %s' % (source, targetName))

# convert *.py to *.pyc and delete the source
source = '/home/vic/ui_form.py'
target = source + 'c' # py -> pyc
py_compile.compile(source, target)
#shutil.copy(target, target + '_') # if uncommented - the *.pyc_ file remains
os.remove(source) # if commented - both *.py and *.pyc files remain, otherwise both deleted (?)
```

I don't know what's happening (see the comments in the code for additional info).

I thought i would have a hint if i find WHO deletes the file - maybe it's pyuic4?

I there a possibility to monitor which process deletes a file?

---

**UPDATE:**

I was debugging step by step. After executing `os.remove(source)` both files (*.py - source, and *.pyc) are deleted.

Could this be some Python behavior?

Comment: ```source=target``` - so target is your .py initially?  Where does this get initialised?  And why do you have ```target``` and ```targetName```?

Comment: sorry i took this from a bigger code. i will simplify this.

Comment: Watch out copy-paste when coding. A **lot** of bugs come from copy-pasting code without really focusing on what's being done. Use generic modules instead of copy-pasting. Also this IMHO fits better in StackOverflow.

Comment: Use strace -f and search for unlink in the log.

Comment: `strace -f` helped - it showed the `unlink` calls, but only `*.py` files where deleted. could there be a race condition, that compiling *.py -> *.pyc is not finished while *.py is being deleted and *.pyc is also deleted by OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going crazy all the day with this issue, and, as it often happens, the solution was near, but of a different kind:

I have this project open in Eclipse. When Eclipse is open it tracks the creation of new *.py files (from *.ui or *qrc). Then Eclipse automatically adds them to the project.

When the script converts *.py files to *.pyc and deletes the *.py files - Eclipse also tracks this and carefully deletes the corresponding *.pyc files.

So this is it.

Answer (score 6):

You can set `sysctl -w vm.block_dump=1` to see every file system action in `dmesg`. (high volume, so disable again afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `inotify` to detect filesystem activity. See the manual. Quoting the manual:

```
       IN_DELETE         File/directory deleted from watched directory (*).
       IN_DELETE_SELF    Watched file/directory was itself deleted.
```

Not sure if you can get who deleted it. Another idea:

```
chattr +i test.py
```

and see if some command tries to unsuccessfully delete it (and gives an error message).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [auditd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html). I haven't tried it, but it might be helpful.